# Fixing nonetype error in my Python function

Tags: python

Here is the function that is producing the error:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    x = len(secretWord)-1
    y = 0
    letter = lettersGuessed[:]
    while y <= x: 
        first=secretWord[y]
        if first in letter:
            return " " + first + " " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord[1:], lettersGuessed[:]))
        else:
            return " _ " + str(getGuessedWord(secretWord[1:], lettersGuessed[:]))    
    return ''
```

It is working as a standalone function, but when I try to pass variables to it in a module I get:

line 4, in getGuessedWord

```
    letter = lettersGuessed[:]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Not really sure where the mistake is. Forgot to mention it is part of a hangman game, so I am passing the random word generated to it as well as a letter guessed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously passing `None` as second argument to this function at some point. You can try adding `print(secretWord, lettersGuessed)` just after start of a function to find how do you get there.

**P.S.** You don't really need to copy `lettersGuessed` each time you refer them.

**P.P.S.** Also, you are not really using while loop, you can just replace it with if.

Comment: I figured out the mistake that was causing the none error, however the function doesn't seem to return what I need it to. For example: if the word was packed and I guessed the letter a it prints out: Please guess a letter: a
packed a
acked a
cked a
ked a
ed a
d a
 a

Comment: Add some prints here and where. Find where printed values contradict what you expect. Move "ok print" and "failed print" towards each other until there is only one line between them. The error is in that line.